# Validate object with mongoose query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need to validate object with mongoose query.

For example, i have object:

```
const user = {username: 'foo', email: 'foo@mail', type: 2};
```

and mongoose query

```
const query = { type: { '$in': [ 2, 1 ] };
```

So i need something like this:

```
const isValid = validate(user, query);  // true
```

Comment: you mean you want to create a custom `validate` function providing the `object` and `query` type

Comment: Yes, but it's  better if there is already realized solution.

Comment: I don't see why you'd need a mongoose query, when you already have the object. Just use `if-else` statements and check against the object.

Answer (score 0):

To validate your data, you can use [`built-in validators`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#built-in-validators), if you need to specify a range :

```
var DataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    email: String,
    type: {
        type: Number,
        min: [1, 'Error type must be > 0'],
        max: [2, 'Error type must be < 3']
    }
});
```

or [`custom validators`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#custom-validators), if you want to check values in an array :

```
var acceptedTypes = [2, 1];

var DataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    email: String,
    type: {
        type: Number,
        validate: {
            validator: function(v) {
                for (var i = 0; i < acceptedTypes.length; i++) {
                    return (acceptedTypes[i] == v);
                }
                return false;
            },
            message: '[type] is not an accepted value'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what i need. I have an application with 5 types of users. User of type 4 can create any type of user, but user of type 3 can create only users of type less than 3. So i need to validate object with query before creating. It's another type of validation